# How to get a unique vector combination whenever the combination of vectors is unique

Tags: combinatorics, vectors

Let's say I have a set of vectors $V$ in some $d$ dimensional space. Is there a method to combine any subset of vectors in $V$ into a new single vector $v$ such that no other combination of vectors will represent $v$? 
 So, given some unknown combination method $m$, taking a set of vectors and outputs a new vector, $m(a) \neq m(b)$ must hold for all subsets $a,b \in S$ (except when $a = b$).

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this just saying the set of vectors is linearly independent?

Comment: What is the domain (inputs) of $m$?  Is it a single vector or a set of vectors?  Since you call it a "combination method" I would assume a typical input is a set of vectors, but then what does $m(i)$ mean?

Comment: It may be easy to misunderstand since I use typical index variable names (i,j), but since they're in S (and S is a set of combinations), they represent subsets of vectors

Comment: @eyeballfrog yes, good point. If they are linear independent, $m$ could just sum the vectors in a subset. But they doesn’t necessarily have to be linear independent. I will add that to the description to make it clear

Comment: @RikardOlsson Does this have to be a linear combination?

Comment: @eyeballfrog no, any combination (but hopefully something computed in linear time)